# How to profile code on raspberry pi?

Tags: linux, arm, bare-metal

Are there any open source or examples for using raspberry pi's ARM cpu's PMU, performance counter?

It can be a bare metal example or user-space application.

I have seen [this](https://github.com/deater/uarch-configure/tree/master/rasp-pi-pmu) and [that](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=19151) (which I don't understand how can I use to profile bare metal code). [This](http://sandsoftwaresound.net/raspberry-pi-performance-counters-part-1/) link is work in progress.

Comment: this question should be re-opened

Comment: @b20000 Notice it was closed *two years* after it was asked, and during that time it received no attention from anyone willing and able to provide an answer.  I likely did this during a spree of closing old questions with no answers to "clean up the site" and help our stats for graduation from beta status.  Anyway, point being you'd be better off just re-asking it...if I reopen this now it will just continue to be ignored for eternity.